# C# Closure binding

Tags: c#, closures

Given the following, when is `foo` bound?

```
 System.Timer t = new System.Timer( (a)=>{
    var foo = Messages.SelectedItem as FooBar;
 });
```

Is it bound then the anonymous method is executed, or when the method is defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`foo` is not bound at all, as it's internal to the anonymous method.  It will call Messages.SelectedItem.  If Messages is an instance property, what is bound is the 'this' instance, which is used to get at Messages.

Answer (score 4):

Never, because of the compile-time error you would get due the absence of a `System.Timer` class in the BCL. Assuming you wanted a [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k93acx8.aspx) then the closure will be bound/captured at the moment this constructor is called i.e. the method is defined. If you want to bind it when the method is executed you need another [constructor overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2x96zfy7.aspx) and pass a state.

```
var t = new System.Threading.Timer(a =>
{
    var foo = a as FooBar;
}, Messages.SelectedItem, -1, -1);
```

Now when the callback runs it will use the `Messages.SelectedItem` value at the moment this callback executes.

Comment: is there anything that you can say "I have no idea about that" Darin?

Comment: @BurnAfterReading, I have no idea who's gonna win Roland Garros this year. I would bet for Federer even though I am a great fan of Djoko.

Comment: :D I would bet for Federer too, and he is my favorite.Let's see what end time brings us.

Comment: @Darin: Maybe I'm misreading, but your explanation seems backwards to me. In the OP's case, the value of `foo` will be set to the current value of `Messages.SelectedItem` each time the method executes. In your answer's code, the value of `foo` is fixed as the value of `Messages.SelectedItem` at the time the constructor is called. Yet you say the value will be the one that is present "at the moment this callback executes", which implies otherwise.

Comment: @Ben M, my English is so poor that I am not even sure to understand your comment :-) But I guess you must be right about my poor choice of words.

Comment: @Darin: that'd be a surprise to me. Anyway, the answer is that `foo` is not captured at all--since it's defined in the lambda. Rather, the captured object is the one that implements the `Messages` property--probably `this`. (In other words, Dan Bryant is right.)

Comment: @Ben M, `foo` is a local variable of the timer callback so we cannot talk about `capturing` it. If something is being captured in a closure here this is the `Messages.SelectedItem` property/field. Also the OP wants to know when is the `foo` variable bound but I guess he used a poor choice of words because `foo` is always bound when the callback executes. I guess that what he wanted to know is to what value is this `foo` variable being assigned.

Comment: @Darin, exactly. But I'm guessing the OP meant 'bound' to mean 'captured'. Otherwise, I'm not sure what the question was about.